# Including PebbleKit appears to create a second launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm writing an Android app that will be able to communicate with a Pebble. Everything seems to be working, except for the fact that the android app creates two seperate launchers.

When selecting the first launcher, the activity that has a launcher-intent declared in the manifest file opens. The second launcher tries to open something too, but this results in an appcrash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nl.eastinc.testapptwo/com.getpebble.android.kit.PEBBLE_KIT}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getpebble.android.kit.PEBBLE_KIT
```

In my /app/build.gradle file I include the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.getpebble:pebblekit:2.5.0'
}
```

This dependency appears to create its own AndroidManifest.xml, which I think creates the second launcher for the activity com.getpebble.android.kit.PEBBLE_KIT. Everytime I delete the launcher-intent rule for this activity it will get regenerated when building the app.

How can I prevent the second launcher (or rather the activity itself) from being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the root manifest node (the manifest of the app) and `tools:node="replace"` to the application node.
It will disable application nodes merging and leave only the main one.

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:node-markers for details.